# safari notification permission always return 'default' after relaunching even the website has allowed notification before

Tags: safari, notifications

My safari version: Version 12.1.1 (14607.2.6.1.1)

Say I am on website A, and I use `Notification.requestPermission()` to allow the notification on it.

Then I quit safari, relaunch it and open website A again, I use `Notification.permission` to get current permission, it always return 'default', even though I can see in the **Preferences->Notifications** that website A has allowed notification.

Ultimate purpose: I need to know correct permission to determine if I need to show some toast for user.